# A question about multivariable functions and bilinear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, group-homomorphism, bilinear-form

How can a bilinear map can be considered to be linear in each of its argument s when there is only one argument to the function $f:X\times X\rightarrow Y $ and that is an element of the set $X\times X$. I can't quite extend the notion of homomorphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$ where $f$ accepts arguments from the vector space only, not an element from the cartesian product of two vector spaces. I understand the definition of the latter, but I can't extend it when it comes to accepting an argument from $X\times X$.

Comment: So you don't accept functions of a complex variable either, since a complex variable involves two real variables?

Comment: I never said anything about accepting, I'm just asking how to think about it and how one makes the extension from the homomorphism I know about to the one I'm asking about.

Comment: Well, it's just a function which, when you fix the value of one variable, becomes linear in the other. Think of the dot product in usual geometry.

Comment: How do you know this is the right extension of the concept of linearity? And also, how to think about bilinearity/multilinearity if I think about the arguments of the function as elements from $X\times X$ not considering the two vectors separately?

Comment: First, how is the domain of a multivariable function/map seen? I see it as all the elements of a cartesian product of $n$ vector spaces. How can one 'split' the vectors from this element that goes in the function as an argument?

Comment: By the canonical projections of the product onto its factors.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by that. May you please elaborate on it? I'm self-taught so I'm sorry if I sound unfamiliar with some terms you consider elementary. Thank you.

Comment: For two factors $E$ and $F$ you have the linear maps \begin{align}E\times F&\longrightarrow E&E\times F&\longrightarrow F\\ (x,y) & \longmapsto x&(x,y) & \longmapsto y \end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be vector spaces over a field $F$. To say that a function $f:X \times X \to Y$ is "linear in each of its arguments" means that the functions $x \mapsto f(x,v)$ and $x \mapsto f(v,x)$ are linear for all $v \in X$.

If you don't like the phrase "linear in each of its arguments", you could use the term "bilinear" instead.  Perhaps that would eliminate the confusion.

Comment: How do we know that this is the right extension of the concept of linearity we know of ordinary linear maps ($f:V\rightarrow W$)? Also, why it's said 'in each of its arguments'? I see one argument here, and it's the element of the cartesian product $X\times X$? Can you say something about this? Thanks.

Comment: When people say "in each of its arguments", they are thinking of $f$ as taking two arguments as input.  You could object that $f$ takes an ordered pair $(u,v)$ as input, and that is only one single argument, not two.  But if they just use the term "multilinear" instead, then there is nothing to object to, and the confusion goes away.

Comment: What do you mean by "the right extension"?  This is *an* extension of the concept of linearity which turns out to be interesting and useful.  Nobody needs to claim that it is "the right extension", although you may come to feel that way if the idea turns out to be fruitful.

Comment: By that I mean, are there other ways to extend the definition or this is the only one? Also, how do you define the bilinearity if the function is said to take one argument that is an element of $X\times X$?

Comment: You are correct that $f$ takes as input an element of $X \times X$.  The definition I gave still makes perfect sense.  Except maybe you object to the notation $f(x,v)$ and would prefer that it were written $f((x,v))$ instead, to emphasize that the input to $f$ is the ordered pair $(x,v)$.  If you prefer that notation, then to say that $f$ is bilinear means that the functions $x \mapsto f((x,v))$ and $x \mapsto f((v,x))$ are linear for all $v \in X$.  I think people get tired of writing these parentheses so they are a bit sloppy and write $f(x,v)$ instead of $f((x,v))$.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't like working with bilinear functions you could avoid them altogether (sort of).

Let $V, W, Z$ be vector spaces. A bilinear map $f : V \times W \to Z$ corresponds to a *linear* map $\tilde{f} : V \otimes W\to Z$, where $V \otimes W$ is the tensor product of vector spaces $V$ and $W$:

Let $\{e_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a basis for $V$, and $\{f_j\}_{j\in J}$ be a basis for $W$.

Then $V \otimes W := \mathrm{span}\{e_i\otimes f_j : i \in I, j \in J\}$.

$v\otimes w$ is pretty much just a fancy notation for $(v, w)$, except that the operations $+$ and $\cdot$ do not obey the classic properties you would have for $X \oplus Y$:

$$(v_1, w_1) + (v_2, w_2) = (v_1+v_2, w_1+w_2)$$
$$\lambda (v_1, w_1) = (\lambda v_1, \lambda v_2)$$

For these objects, however, we have:

$$(v_1, w) + (v_2, w) = (v_1+v_2, w)$$
$$(v, w_1) + (v, w_2) = (v, w_1+w_2)$$
$$\lambda (v, w) = (\lambda v, w) = (v, \lambda w)$$

In other words, the operation $\otimes : X \times Y \to X \otimes Y$ is bilinear.

Now for a bilinear map $f : V \times W \to Z$, define $\tilde{f} : V \otimes W \to Z$ on its basis:

$$\hat{f}(e_i \otimes f_j) := f(e_i, f_j)$$

Lo and behold, $\tilde{f}$ is a linear map.

To answer your question, your bilinear map $f : X \times X \to Y$ could be interpreted as a linear function on $X \otimes X$, not $X \times X$.